# How to ensure an OnEndRequest filter runs in ServiceStack after a request is failed by ValidationFeature's global filter?

Tags: servicestack, response

I have a ServiceStack API (3.9.58).  I'm using statsd to time request-execution, by means of implementing an IPlugin that registers a global request filter and global response filter (I know about the RequestLogFeature; this isn't the only thing this thing does).  It sticks a started `Stopwatch` in the items collection when the request starts, and pulls it out again once the request completes.

```
    .....
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.RequestFilters.Add(OnBeginRequest);
        appHost.ResponseFilters.Add(OnEndRequest);
    }
    .....
```

This works a treat (just like it does in the `ServiceRunner`, where `IRequestLogger` does the same thing).

However, when I added validation using the out-of-the-box `ValidationFeature`, I stopped getting timing information for requests that dumped 4xx because of requests not satisfying my validation rules.

I've seen from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526236/global-request-response-interceptor) that global response filters are supposed to fire no matter what the status is.  But for me, they're not.  Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that global response filters are not always executed, and you need to either register some additional types of callbacks to handle certain cases, or take an approach such as subclassing the `ServiceRunner` class.

The SO question you linked states that "global response filters are executed no matter what status code is returned by the service". What this says is that when a service successfully *returns a response object*, global response filters should always be executed. However, a service or plugin may instead throw an exception or call `EndServiceStackRequest`, in which case that assertion does not apply.

In the case of an exception, the `ServiceRunner` will invoke any global [exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15604622/795339) you may have registered with the `AppHost`.

To handle the case of a validation failure, you could set callback function for the [`ErrorResponseFilter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16065721/795339) property of the `ValidationFetaure` object that you register as a plugin in AppHost.

The alternative would be to subclass [`ServiceRunner`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/ServiceRunner.cs) and override the `Execute` method (and implement [`CreateServiceRunner`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531595/795339)), or maybe register an HTTP module, in order to have one set of code that always executes at the end of a request.

*More details on what happens in the case of a validation failure:* the [filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Validation/ValidationFilters.cs) set up by the ValidationFeature calls a [`WriteToResponse`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/IHttpResponseExtensions.cs#L66) extension method with the error info in the case of a validation failure, which eventually calls `EndServiceStackRequest`. In this case, the ServiceRunner will simply return early from the `Execute` method. The ServiceRunner will not invoke the service action, or run response filters, or invoke the `OnAfterExecute` method.